# How do I convert this threeCanvas.js line of code into three.js?

Tags: matrix-multiplication, three.js

For whatever reason, three.js and ThreeCanvas.js are incompatible.  I'm attempting to change a ThreeCanvas.js program over to three.js, but this line is giving me huge problems:

```
var position = new THREE.Vector3().add(
   intersect.point,
   intersect.object.matrixRotation.transform( intersect.face.normal.clone() ) 
);
```

The problem is that neither "THREE.Object3D matrixRotation" nor "THREE.Matrix4 transform" exist in three.js, and there appear to be no equivalent methods under different names.  There is, for example, "THREE.Object3D matrixRotationWorld", but the code is entirely different.

Does anyone know how to rewrite this in three.js?